# What is the iteration process of doing PCA and what does convergence mean?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I was doing a principal component analysis on a set of scale items in SPSS and noticed that we can set the number of "maximum iterations for convergence" in the dialog box. I googled the meaning of "iterations" and "convergence" but only found more questions on why "rotations failed to converge in 25 iterations". Many responses simply suggested that one should increase the maximum iterations for convergence to 50 or 100 without really explaining what the error message meant.

May I ask what is actually meant by the error message and under what circumstances it pops out? And what is the iteration process like, i.e. what are the input values and what is the algorithm?

Thank you!

Comment: The reference to "rotations" sounds like you're doing *factor analysis* rather than PCA, so it would help to tell us exactly what options you have specified.

Comment: I was doing a scale development class project. The project guideline suggests that I do an EFA using the principal components method; I thought PCA stood for this extraction method... Both the extraction of factors and the rotation were successful using my dataset. I just wonder what "iteration" and "convergence" actually mean and why rotation sometimes fails... Thank you!